# Как вернуть стандартную ubuntu 17.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

`Ubuntu 17.10` обновился и стал `ubuntu mate 17.10`.

Как можно его откатить назад?

Comment: если он был 17.10, то как он обновился до 17.10? у Вас точно чистая убунта или какая то поделка вида mint/..?

Comment: Вчера была чистая Ubuntu 17.10. Сегодня утром включаю, а там Ubuntu Mate 17,10

Comment: Вчера до выключения он обновлялся. Но ничего такого я не замечал.

Comment: может быть у Вас была убунта 17.04 c unity?  а в 17.10 от нее решили отказаться

Comment: Я сразу установил 17.10. 17,04 я убрал при переустановке

Comment: А откатить ее как-нибудь можно?

Comment: значит нужно открывать папку с логами apt /var/log/apt/ и искать, что там лишнего установилось

Comment: не нравится *mate* — выберите любой другой *de* при логине: `google://ubuntu+switch+desktop+environment`

Comment: Это магия какая-то. Чтобы в линуксе при апгрейде появлялись совершенно несвязанные со старыми новые пакеты, я ещё не слышал.

Comment: за что так заминусовали?

Answer (score 2):

На окне входа есть выбор DE, с которым вы хотите работать. [Выглядит как на скриншотах.](https://askubuntu.com/a/400581/135652)

Если у вас нет, то это может быть [этот баг, с описанием исправления](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awesome/+bug/1094811).